# UISegmentControl truncate title on iOS 7 inconsistently

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios7, uisegmentedcontrol

Strangely my old app (project built with XCode 4.x & iOS 6 sdk) when installed on devices with iOS 7, the title strings of all the segments gets truncated - show only 3-5 characters followed by overflow dots(...) *inconsistently*.

Key points/observations -

1. It happens on both iPhone or iPad with iOS 7 sdk but not on iOS 6 devices.
2. The title strings are static (small 5 to 10 characters in 3 segments) such that they easily fit on their segments with no text overflow (...)
3. On iPhone and iPad with iOS 6, there is no issue. Works fine on simulator as well as device.
4. Even on iOS 7, the first time it renders the text fine (no overflow) but when you play around with app and come back on that view third or fourth time, then the issue arises.
5. Note the app is built with XCode 4.x (iOS 6 sdk) and not iOS 7 look & feel compliant.
6. My app uses two different segmentcontrol (one with 2 segments and other with 3 segments) inside 2 different views and whenever issue arises it happens on both of them.

Anyone else faced this issue?

Comment: are you changing frame size ?

Comment: yes, I'm changing frame sizes to support orientations. In one of the 2 segment controls, i am setting widths to it's indexes.`self.userType.frame = relativeFrame;
    [self.userType setWidth:5*relativeFrame.size.width/12 forSegmentAtIndex:kGWTalkUserDriver];
    [self.userType setWidth:7*relativeFrame.size.width/12 forSegmentAtIndex:kGWTalkUserDispatcher];`
However the title truncation issue appears in both different segment controls.

Comment: When you are changing frame then it shrink your text, make it as large  as text value visible

Answer (score 1):

There is a straightforward way to fix this. You can use the property`apportionsSegmentWidthsByContent` and set it to`YES`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by setting the same title text attributes that I had for the normal state, for the selected state.
In iOS 6 this was enough:

```
NSMutableDictionary *attributes = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   someUIFont, UITextAttributeFont,
                                   nil];

[self.segmentedControl setTitleTextAttributes:attributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Now I had to add this in order to make it work for iOS 7:

```
[self.segmentedControl setTitleTextAttributes:attributes forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Comment: Thanks. But this answer comes in very late.. I'm not sure I will be able to verify this because I have moved on to ios7 sdk (Xcode 5). It was an issue until I was building the work-in-progress app with with ios6 sdk (Xcode 4). Just for records, I admit that I was not setting any title attributes both for normal or/and selected state.